# how to see git merge conflict in meld after merge performed with no merge tool set

Tags: git, merge

I performed git merge and there are some conflict.
No external merge-tool was set and for some reason I don't want to do it.
Now I would like to resolve these conflicts with meld.
what to do?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: meld with "version control" comparison chosen.
My question was a result of another problem which I didn't realized.
git have to be installed and available to meld in order to see merge results.
Maybe this will help someone.